# Pre-caching of maps with google map android API v2

Tags: android, api, dictionary

I need to do map pre-cache of any zone previously chosen in my app. Is it possible to do this with google map android API v2? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is the google map *seems to be cached* automatically on android.  Have you even tried to see what the response time is on a zone that was previously visited in your application?

Anywho,

It's against the terms of service to cache the google map for most situations.  It's against the terms of service of course to reverse-engineer.  You have to call the service via the api so I don't see how you can pre-cache the "MAP" legally.

See section 10.1.3 subsection (b) https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

10.1.3 Restrictions against Data Export or Copying.

...

(b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.